# Perl - Using a Variable that is inside an if statement

Tags: perl, variables, if-statement, scope

I've been putting together a Perl script that defines a variable, and then via an `if` statement will assign a new value to the variable.

I want to use the last assigned value from the `if` statement and reference it somewhere else outside the `if` altogether.

It appears that when referencing it that it uses the original value.

Here's the code:

```
## VARIABLES
my $FILENAME = $input[0];

open my $info, $DATAFILE or die "can't open <$DATAFILE> for reading $!";

{
  while (my $line = <$info>) {

    chomp $line;
    my @input = split(':', $line);
    chomp(@input);

    $FILENAME     = $input[0];
    $PERMIT       = $input[1];
    $FILESIZE     = -s "$TIFF_DL_LOCATION/$PERMIT\_$FILENAME";
    $SHORT_PERMIT = substr($PERMIT, 0, 2);

    ### DEBUG ONLY ###
    print "$FILENAME / $PERMIT / $FTPBASE/$SHORT_PERMIT/$PERMIT/$FILENAME\n";

    my $ftp = Net::FTP::Throttle->new(
      "example.com",
      MegabitsPerSecond => $THROTTLELVL,
      Debug             => $DEBUGLVL
    ) or die "Cannot connect: $@";

    $ftp->login("anonymous", 'anonymous') or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
    $ftp->binary or die "Unable to set binary mode ", $ftp->message;

    if ($PROGRESSBAR eq 1) {

      print "\n[$./$LINE_COUNT] Downloading $FILENAME\n";
      my $REMOTE_FILESIZE = $ftp->size("/PATH/TO/DATA/$SHORT_PERMIT/$PERMIT/$FILENAME");

      if (!defined($REMOTE_FILESIZE)) {

        print "=> FILE DOES NOT APPEAR TO EXIST ON FTP SERVER\n";

        if ($FILENAME =~ m/_\s/) {

          print "=> ATTEMPTING TO FIX NOW\n";
          $FILENAME =~ s/_\s/, /g;
          $REMOTE_FILESIZE = $ftp->size("/PATH/TO/DATA/$SHORT_PERMIT/$PERMIT/$FILENAME");

          if (!defined($REMOTE_FILESIZE)) {
            print "=> FAILED!\n";
          }
        }
        elsif ($FILENAME =~ m/_\s\s/) {

          print "=> ATTEMPTING TO FIX NOW\n";
          $FILENAME =~ s/_\s\s/, /g;
          $REMOTE_FILESIZE = $ftp->size("/PATH/TO/DATA/$SHORT_PERMIT/$PERMIT/$FILENAME");

          if (!defined($REMOTE_FILESIZE)) {
            print "$FILENAME\n";
            print "=> FAILED!\n";
          }
        }
        else {
          print "=> ALL ATTEMPTS TO RESOLVE THE ISSUE HAVE FAILED.\n";
          next;
        }
      }

      $REMOTE_FILESIZE = $ftp->size("/PATH/TO/DATA/$SHORT_PERMIT/$PERMIT/$FILENAME");
      print "FILENAME: $FILENAME\n";

      --- SNIP SNIP - MORE DATA, NOT RELEVANT--
```

The output I get is the name of the file that was originally opened, not the value after modification by the substitutions in the `if` statements.

This is error correction: it checks the filename that it gets from the file, and if it matches something, it corrects it, and in the end, I have an old variable `$FILENAME` with a new value that I want to use outside the `if`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I don't see any code where $FILENAME ever gets reassigned.   If you want the value of $FILENAME to change then I'd expect to see "$FILENAME = ..." somewhere in the code besides the original assignment.  Instead I only see $FILENAME =~ which is a search binding operator, totally different.

Comment: You might have a typo.  Put 'use strict;' and 'use warning;' at the top of your script.  It'll warn you about variables redefined in a different scope.

Comment: @sabertiger - I use those two items by default, just left them out.  No typo, per the output.

Comment: @drewrockshard did you try printing  $FILENAME before and after ' $FILENAME =~ s/_\s/, /g;' in the if/elsif block to check if there is actually a substitution or if the if/elsif block predicate is satisfied.

Comment: I agree with keety.  The '$FILENAME =~ m/_\s\s/' will never be matched because it will always match '$FILENAME =~ m/_\s/' first.

Comment: @drewrockshard: I have edited your question to make it a little more readable. Please check to make sure it says what you intended

Comment: There is only one `$FILENAME`, so the `print` is showing you the real value of the variable and your diagnosis must be wrong. Please show the output from your program that shows which conditional statements were executed

Comment: @keety and @sabertiger - both hit the nail on the head.  The overall solution was to call `$FILENAME =~ m/_\s\s/` and THEN `$FILENAME =~ m/_\s/` (both within their own `if` statement).  Once I used this order, it worked perfectly!  Thanks for opening my eyes to this discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to understand the code in your question, mainly because of all the upper case strings; both identifiers and comments

Local identifiers in most languages, including Perl, are usually written using lower-case letters, digits, and the underscore `_`. Capital letters are reserved for *global* variables, and in Perl's case that is mostly package (class) names

Identifiers of important variables use capital letters so that they stand out from the rest; but in your example *most* identifiers are all-capitals. It is diffifult to understand the structure of your code if *every* identifier says it's very important

I have looked carefully at the code you show, and have done my best to reorganise and simplify it so that it is more legible and does what I think you intended. I have added declarations for all of the variables that are not declared within your code sample, and have added what I think are the correct closing braces `}` to balance the syntax so that it will compile

As others have noted, the second conditional clause that tests for underscore followed by *two* spaces will never be executed, because the preceding test for underscore followed by *one* space will already have caught that case. It is also pointless to use a separate pattern match to determine whether a substitution `s///` will succeed, as the substitution alone does nothing and returns a *false* value if there was no match

The intention is to help you to write Perl code that *you* can understand, as well as others who you may ask for help (like Stack Overflow) or may be given the job of maintaining your software.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($progressbar, $line_count);
my ($datafile, $ftpbase, $short, $tiff_dl_location);
my ($throttlelvl, $debuglvl);
my @input;

## Variables
my $filename = $input[0];

open my $info, $datafile or die "can't open <$datafile> for reading $!";

{
  while (<$info>) {

    chomp;
    my ($filename, $permit) = split /:/;

    my $filesize = -s "$tiff_dl_location/${permit}_${filename}";
    my $short_permit = substr $permit, 0, 2;

    ### DEBUG ONLY ###
    print "$filename / $permit / $ftpbase/$short_permit/$permit/$filename\n";

    my $file_path = "/PATH/TO/DATA/$short_permit/$permit/$filename";

    my $ftp = Net::FTP::Throttle->new(
      "example.com",
      MegabitsPerSecond => $throttlelvl,
      Debug             => $debuglvl
    ) or die "Cannot connect: $@";

    $ftp->login(qw/ anonymous anonymous /) or die "Cannot login: ", $ftp->message;
    $ftp->binary or die "Unable to set binary mode ", $ftp->message;

    if ($progressbar == 1) {

      print "\n[$./$line_count] Downloading $filename\n";
      my $remote_filesize = $ftp->size($file_path);

      if (not defined $remote_filesize) {

        warn "=> File does not appear to exist on FTP server\n";
        warn "=> Attempting to fix now\n";

        $filename =~ s/_\s+/, /g;
        $remote_filesize = $ftp->size($file_path);

        if (not defined $remote_filesize) {
          warn "=> ALL ATTEMPTS TO RESOLVE THE ISSUE HAVE FAILED.\n";
          next;
        }
      }

      print "File name: $filename\n";

      # --- snip snip - more data, not relevant ---

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables outside of (before) the conditional unless they will only be used inside of that conditional block {}.

Also, 
    use strict;
    use warnings;